# Why wont Visual Studio show me all tenants in Microsoft Identity Platform?

Tags: visual-studio

When I right-click `Connected Services` inside a Visual Studio ASP.NET app, and select `Add->Microsoft Identity Platform` I see the following...

(Note, I don't mind that my email address is visible).

The word `[Filtered]` appears next to my account and I cannot select the tenant I want because it is not present in the list.

I've tried signing out and back in again, but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem, do the following

1. Open Visual Studio
2. `File` menu
3. `Account settings` menu item
4. Click `Apply filter` against the account you are having problems with

[image: Apply filter]

5. Check the `Select all` checkbox
6. Click the `Apply` button
7. Above `Apply filter` click `Remove` to remove the account
8. Re-add the account

You may need to restart Visual Studio.